# Reference a MySQL calculated/dynamic column or subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables - leads and brochures. Each sales lead that comes in can request zero or more brochures. I can write the following query to get the number of brochures requested per lead:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM brochures WHERE lead = l.id) AS 'BrochureCount'
FROM leads l
```

If I want to only show leads which have requested some brochures, I can repeat the subquery in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM brochures WHERE lead = l.id) AS 'BrochureCount'
FROM leads l
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM brochures WHERE lead = l.id) > 0
```

But this will presumable run the subquery twice, resulting in an even slower query.

Is it possible to reference `BrochureCount` in the WHERE clause, either by name, column number or some other format?

Thanks for your time,

Adam

Comment: If the query planner can't rewrite it to a join, the subquery has to be resolved as many times as there are leads, not just twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what it's called, and that it can't be done.

It's called a column alias, and apparently it can't be used in a `WHERE` clause. From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE
>   clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is
>   executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

Answer (score 0):

The leads and how many brochures they ordered, if at least 1:

```
SELECT
  leads.id,
  COUNT(brochures.lead) AS `BrochureCount`
FROM
  leads
INNER JOIN
  brochures
ON
  leads.id = brochures.lead
GROUP BY
  leads.id
```

If you wanted all the leads and brochure counts even if they have 0 associated brochures:

```
SELECT
  leads.id,
  COUNT(brochures.lead) AS `BrochureCount`
FROM
  leads
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  brochures
ON
  leads.id = brochures.lead
GROUP BY
  leads.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Dan. I was particularly after a way of referencing my calculated columns though - the example I gave was a very basic example - the query I'm writing is far more complex and will have many calculated columns or subqueries.

Comment: If you want a more applicable answer then post a real query, not a dumbed down example. There's no catch-all answer in such a large domain of possible queries. In reality though, even very complex dependent subqueries can often be rewritten with joins and aggregation (and for MySQL, a performance increase, as the planner tends to do better with joins than subqueries).

Comment: For example, I recently wrote a query that does cohort analysis on a generic people and events (things those people have done) data set. That means grouping all the people by the day/week/month they first performed some event, then determining what percentage of that group performed the same event type again in the next 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7 days/weeks/months. Over some time period, I want to create 7 cohorts and track them for up to 7 time periods, and determine the percentage that are still active for each time period. This is two levels of moving date-level groupings...

Comment: ...up to 7 sets of people and 7 groups of dates, with calculations on those intersections, and it is accomplished with a single query and no subqueries. I'm confident we could rewrite your calculations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT id, BrochureCount
FROM(
    SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM brochures WHERE lead = l.id) AS 'BrochureCount'
    FROM leads l) data
Where data.BrochureCount > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straighforward way to reference a calculated column is with a HAVING clause. In general:

```
<subquery> HAVING <expression>
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * from (<subquery>) WHERE <expression>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question